# Using Java classpath to execute Java 9+ Services

Tags: java, classpath

I have created a simple Java9 service example with one service interface and two service implementations and one driver which uses the ServiceLoader. I was able to successfully execute the example with module-path but when I tried to execute the same with java -cp (classpath) I did not get any output, not even any error.

#### Directory structure

```
out
├── driver
│   ├── com
│   │   └── company
│   │       └── driver
│   │           └── driver.class
│   └── module-info.class
├── firstServiceImpl
│   ├── com
│   │   └── company
│   │       └── first
│   │           └── serviceImpl
│   │               └── FunImpl1.class
│   └── module-info.class
├── secondServiceImpl
│   ├── com
│   │   └── company
│   │       └── second
│   │           └── serviceImpl
│   │               └── FunImpl2.class
│   └── module-info.class
└── serviceInterface
    ├── com
    │   └── company
    │       └── service
    │           └── Fun.class
    └── module-info.class
```

#### command to compile

```
javac -d out --module-source-path src src/driver/driver.java src/firstServiceImpl/FunImpl1.java src/secondServiceImpl/FunImpl2.java src/serviceInterface/Fun.java
```

The above command compiles the code with a ***module-source-path***.

#### command to run

```
java -cp out/driver:out/serviceInterface/:out/firstServiceImpl/ com.sunil.driver.driver
```

The above command runs the code with a ***classpath***.

After compiling with ***module-source-path*** and run the code with ***classpath***. I do not get any error or output.
Please help me understand why there is no output when run using ***classpath***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way service-providers are located depends on if the service-providers are on the classpath or the modulepath. This is described in the documentation of [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html):

> ### Deploying service providers as modules
>
> A service provider that is developed in a module must be specified in a *provides* directive in the module declaration. The provides directive specifies both the service and the service provider; this helps to locate the provider when another module, with a *uses* directive for the service, obtains a service loader for the service. It is strongly recommended that the module does not export the package containing the service provider. There is no support for a module specifying, in a *provides* directive, a service provider in another module.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Deploying service providers on the class path
>
> A service provider that is packaged as a JAR file for the class path is identified by placing a *provider-configuration file* in the resource directory `META-INF/services`. The name of the provider-configuration file is the fully qualified binary name of the service. The provider-configuration file contains a list of fully qualified binary names of service providers, one per line.
>
> [...]

Basically, if you want to be able to load a service-provider no matter if it's placed on the classpath or modulepath you'll need to specify both a `provides` directive in the `module-info.java` file and add the appropriate provider-configuration file under `META-INF/services`. You also have to make sure you use the correct method for loading the service-providers:

- [`ServiceLoader#load(Class,ClassLoader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class,java.lang.ClassLoader))

  - Locates providers in named modules (i.e. modulepath) and unnamed modules (i.e. classpath).
- [`ServiceLoader#load(ModuleLayer,Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.ModuleLayer,java.lang.Class))

  - Only locates providers in named modules (i.e. modulepath).